# Laravel - Class 'Socialite' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

Hi there I have problem with Socialite.

I have installed everything how was in GitHub - https://github.com/laravel/socialite but I don't know why but always I have this same problem 
[image: screenshot]

Thanks,
S

Answer (score 0):

Put the `use Socialite;` at the top of the `UserController.php` file.